# Guess and check method, proper name?

Tags: numerical-methods, terminology

> I have been trying to find out if there is a proper name for the guess and check method?

I have been searching and only ever see it referred to as the guess and check method.

Comment: Without being more specific about your technique, the only application term is "trial and error".   In a sense, most numerical methods fall into this category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trial and error seems to be the overarching name for it, and within elementary algebra, the proper name does seem to be guess and check. In the field of computer science, it's called generate and test, brute force search, or exhaustive search. This might also be called the brute force attack, like in cryptography. I've personally always heard it called plug and chug (though this could not be a direct equivalent). More information about this is found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_and_error).

Comment: "plug and chug" refers not to "guess and check" but to rote substitution into a formula.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, guess and check *is* rote substitution into a formula.

Comment: I'd say that how exactly one should "update" their guess falls beyond what plug and chug usually refers to.